# merging two arrays in a specific way

Tags: php, arrays, pattern-matching

I want to combine two arrays with almost same values. I always want to insert an array element into the combined array if it exists.
For:

```
$b = array("a","a","b","a","a","x")

$a = array("a","a","b","x","a","a")
```

I want to have the output:

```
$ab = array ("a","a","b","x","a","a","x");
```

The function `array_merge` or `array_combine` does not work.

Comment: Can you expand a little on what is your logic?

Comment: I had one array which I manipulated in two different ways and therefore got two separated arrays at the end and I want to glue it to one again...

Comment: Ok, but what's the logic behind joining them? What do you mean by "insert an array element into the combined array if it exists"? Exists in what? And which one is being inserted in which?

Answer (score 1):

I would maybe try using `array_splice()`. You'd have to try this on different arrays to see if it works in all scenarios:

```
<?php
$b = array("a","a","b","a","a","x");
$a = array("a","a","b","x","a","a");

function iterateToEven(&$a,&$b)
    {
        $c  =   count($a);
        for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
            if(isset($a[$i])){
                if(isset($b[$i])) {
                    if($a[$i] == $b[$i])
                        continue;
                    else {
                        if(isset($b[$i+1]) && ($b[$i+1] == $a[$i]))
                            array_splice($a,$i,0,$b[$i]);
                        elseif(isset($a[$i+1]) && ($a[$i+1] == $b[$i]))
                            array_splice($b,$i,0,$a[$i]);
                        else
                            array_splice($a,$i,0,$b[$i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(end($a) != end($b)) {
            if(count($a) == count($b))
                iterateToEven($a,$b);
        }

        return (count($a) > count($b))? $a : $b;
    }

$d  =   iterateToEven($a,$b);

print_r($d);
```

Gives the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => a
    [2] => b
    [3] => x
    [4] => a
    [5] => a
    [6] => x
)
```

One caveat, this method will modify both the `$a` & `$b` arrays in the process of doing this function so if you wanted to keep both `$a` and `$b` intact, you could wrap the function application inside another function and return `$d`.

Answer (score 0):

I used following code

```
$b = array("a","a","b","a","a","x");
$a = array("a","a","b","x","a","a");
$list = []; //empty array

for ($i=0; $i < count($a) ; $i++) { 
   for ($j=$i; $j <=$i ; $j++) { 

       if ($i== $j) {
           $list[] = $a[$i]; //if values are equal, list[] gets array a value
       }
       else{
        $list[] = $b[$j];
       }
   }
}

return $list;
```

Result is : `["a","a","b","x","a","a"]`

Comment: the result should be `["a","a","b","x","a","a","x"]`. There is a `x` missing at the end...

Comment: @MoeJoe I am interested to know if you tried my answer on other arrays?